# star rating is not getting added to my custom open graph action suggest

Tags: facebook-opengraph, publish

I have created a custom action suggest. I want to add star rating with this action like goodread do. But I do not find any way to attach star rating, One thing I found was **rate** action. But it applies only on books where as i have a number of objects in my application.

Thanks

Rohit